# Read all CSV file in folder and read a content belong to specific header and write data to 1 CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have to process multiple CSV files as below
[image: Sample csv file]

as you guys can see this CSV file includes 2 rows header with different header length. I just want to read all the content belong to the 1st `header("1_LENGTH,2_LENGTH,START_POS,END_POS,RESULT_HIS,START_FRAME,START_SUPER_FRAME")` only. And write it to the only 1 CSV file.
So is there any way to do it. Thank you guys so much

My code till now as below :

```
def total():
for in_path in Path(log_path).glob('*.csv'):
    out_path =Path(os.getcwd()+"/").with_name("TOTAL.csv")
    with in_path.open('r') as fin, out_path.open('w') as fout:
        header = ['CT_LENGTH', 'T_LENGTH', 'START_POS', 'END_POS','RESULT_HIS','START_FRAME', 'START_SUPER_FRAME']
        reader = pd.read_csv(fin,index_col=False,delim_whitespace=False)
        writer = reader[header].to_csv()
        # raw = '\n'.join(writer)
        print (writer)
        # fout.writable()
return
```

Comment: There must be dozens of duplicates of pretty much exactly this question on this site. Also: *what have you tried?* — This website isn’t a code writing service.

Comment: you just need to add in an `if` statement or use an exception block. if you show your own code we can nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: @KonradRudolph hello i tried to read all csv file in directory but stuck in the step read content in the 1st header only T_T. So if you have any way to do it please let me know T_T.

Comment: @ Umar.H i tried to read some topic but can't figure out how to do it T_T. i added my code till now but still stuck in how to read only 1st header. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The bash script below takes whatever arguments follow the command and treats them all as CSV files. It also assumes that they all have the **same** header rows and creates one massive CSV in the same directory as the first file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# combine selected items into one master csv

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
  echo "Combine multiple CSV files into one preserving the header of the first file"
  echo "Output file is created in the same directory as the first file"
  echo " "
  echo "Use: "
  echo "$0 file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv pattern*.csv"
  exit 0
fi

FIRST=1
OUTPATH=$(dirname "$1")
TIME=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)
OUTPUT=$OUTPATH/all_combined-$TIME.csv

for var in "$@"
do
  if [ $FIRST -gt 0 ]; then
    FIRST=0
    cat "$var" > "$OUTPUT"
  else
    tail -n+2 "$var" >> "$OUTPUT"
  fi
  echo "added $var to $OUTPUT"
done
```

Use:
`$ combine.sh one.csv two.csv HOME*.csv`

Comment: Thank you i'll try this solution later . due to i'm practicing in python so i'm finding a solution using python and pandas lib to . Thank you so much